# Bash/WSL2: Is it possible to send files into the Windows directory from Linux?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, youtube-dl

```
#!/bin/bash

youtube-dl \
--ignore-errors \
--no-playlist \
--prefer-free-formats \
--no-call-home \
--extract-audio \
$1 \
--output 'C:\Users\Daniel\Music\Other\$2.%(ext)s'
```

Right now this script just puts the downloaded file into PWD, with that entire string as it's name. My question is:
Is it possible to use a Windows folder as a destination, or is this a limitation of WSL?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want `$2` to be substituted, it needs to be in double quotes, not single quotes. That part of this question is a duplicate; if you can factor it out of your question, the rest might be on-topic (each question should have only one question, and that question needs to not be already asked-and-answered).

Comment: BTW, the `wslpath` utility may be of use or interest.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah, didn't know that. Fixed. And thank you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That utility is interesting. Apparently I didn't understand how WSL directories worked. It translated the Windows path to a WSL path, but instead of directing the file the script created all the directories in the path, with the file at the bottom. No idea why, but when I ran the script in the root directory, it worked perfectly since all those folder were there. Any idea why it behaved that way?

Answer (score 0):

in the wsl the default mount point for `C:` is `/mnt/c/`

so change the last line to:

```
"/mnt/c/Users/Daniel/Music/Other/$2.%(ext)s"
```

double quotes (see comment from @CharlesDuffy)